# how to add new fieds and use existing address fields in magento custom regstration form

Tags: magento

hi  i am new  to magento.. i need some help..

1. i am able to add address fields in form in my view(phtml file) but that fields data is not being

   saved . how could i be able to save those fields?
   **code for address field in phtml file**

   ```
   <div class="form-group margin_top">
   <label for="street_1" class="required col-md-4 control-label"><?php echo $this->__('Adresse') ?><em>* :</em></label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3 nopaddingright">
               <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
               <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text form-control <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-9 address_block">
               <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                   <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                       <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>"    title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="form-control input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                   <?php endfor; ?>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-9 nopaddingright">
               <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="form-control input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 address_block">
               <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text form-control validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text form-control <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" />
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

2 . i also need mobile(cell) field to be added into my form how can i add that and save into my

database. 
 do i need to create Custom module ?  please suggest me and help me

Thank you

Comment: you can not add the new field directly from Phtml file. you need to create module for that. if you want to add new field in registration form then use this extension. It will definitely help . http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15903/

Comment: Thank you vishal is it compatible for 1.8 version

Comment: definitely it will work on the 1.8 version......Have you install this extenstion ?

Comment: Yes i tried to but it from admin section i am able to configure but i dont know how to use it ( i mean to display that field in view). thanks